# How can I test fields of a multi-line output of a command for a bash script?

Tags: bash

Example output of said command:

```
user@machine:~$ qy glin list-name
name:           list-name
maillist:       1
...similar lines that look like this...
modby:          user
modwith:        tool
```

In the script, I want to be able to say in a IF statement:

If modby = userfoo and modwith = toolbar, do xyz.

I can match the output of a command that can pump out a single line, but don't know how to deal with a command that spews out multiple lines.

Comment: That data looks basically like [Record-Jar](https://books.google.com/books?id=H4q1t-jAcBIC&pg=PA116&dq=record-jar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=y8PxVNKrBOLIsQSgj4GoAQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=record-jar&f=false). There appear to be several tools for parsing RJs in [C](http://openrj.sourceforge.net/), Python, and php, but, remarkably, I couldn't find anything built for handling it directly in shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elegant way to that might be to use Awk:

```
qy glin list-name | awk '{
        if (($1=="modby:")&&($2=="user")) A=1;
        if (($1=="modwith:")&&($2=="tool")) B=1;}
        END {exit A&&B}'

 if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo FOUND
 fi
```

Note that if you want to test for ordered and consecutive lines, you can use such command:

```
 qy glin list-name | awk '{if (($1=="modby:")&&($2=="user")) {
           getline; if (($1=="modwith:")&&($2=="tool")) exit 1;}}'
```

Comment: I said that using awk might be elegant, not that my example wasn't perfectible... But I took your kind remark into account.

Comment: It's much better now `:)`.

Comment: I think I'll go with this, since it's trivial to implement this into a while loop reading a list of list-names. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe/redirect the output of your command to a `while read -r line; do...[insert your if condition with actions here] done`.

`read` reads the output line-by-line and you probably already know how to match the output of a single line. You can also make `read` read a line into more than one variables if it contains white spaces.

For your example, the following (that could be written as a one-liner—but isn't for readability) would work on `bash`:

```
while read -r key value; do
        if [[ $key = modby: ]]; then
            user=$value
        elif [[ $key = modwith: ]]; then
            tool=$value
        fi
        if [[ $user = "user" && $tool = "tool" ]]; then
            printf 'MTFBWY!\n'; unset user tool;
        fi
    done < <(qy glin list-name)
```

..while this may not be optimal solution, it would work for your question.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I edited your post so that the one-liner becomes readable. I hope you don't mind. Your design is rather good, but I have several suggestions: 1. don't run the `while` loop in a subshell; instead use a process substitution: `while ... done < <(qy glin list-name)`. 2. Use `read -r key value` instead of reading the entire line in a single variable; so that you don't need regex: `[[ $key = modby: ]]`, etc. will be simpler. Moreover, by doing so, you won't have to parse the line explicitly with `cut`, you'll only need: `user=$value`, etc.

Comment: And a final suggestion: after printing `MTFBWY`, you might want to unset `tool` and `user` (or use a flag) so that you won't get several of these printed for each other line that doesn't contain `modby` or `modwith`̣—or you can break the loop, but this depends on what OP really wants.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @gniourf_gniourf. I thought about parsing each word but reading `key value` seems very beautiful because `value` would contain rest of the line(so even names with white spaces would work). I'll edit that part. I believe process substitution is better because it doesn't create another shell. And that takes more CPU time, is that correct?
I did think about unsetting the variables but I must admit I do not know an elegant way to do that.

Comment: About process substitution: I don't know about CPU time. The overhead is negligible in this case anyways (you'll have only 1 subshell instead of 2, not really a big deal, but still slightly preferable). It's just that your `while` loop would run in the main shell, so anything you perform is not discarded when the loop ends. And it's nicer too. About unsetting the variables: either clear their content with `user= tool=`, or unset them explicitly with `unset user tool`.

Comment: thanks for sharing the knowledge! I have edited the code once again.

Answer (score 0):

What about turning the script output into shell code that you can execute? Assuming the words in the first column are valid as shell variable names and the words in the second column don't contain single quotes, using this sed script might work:

```
$ qy glin list-name | sed "s/\([^:]*\): *\(.*\)/\1='\2'/"
name='list-name'
maillist='1'
modby='user'
modwith='tool'
```

You could either `source` or `eval` the result and do whatever you want with all the variables.

Comment: But what if there's a line like `modby: '; rm *` in the file? `source` and `eval` should _never_ be used with user input. They are not made for this purpose!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf is right. I can't think of any issues cases where there'd be bad data, but this doesn't appear to be good practice in general.

Comment: While in general there may be a point, I think it's overly paranoid in this specific case.